# Возвращает список той же длины, что и L, где значение в индексе i равно True, если L[i] больше порогового значения, и False в противном случае

Tags: python

Не знаю как правильно решить данную задачу,сталкиваюсь с отсутствием индекса в диапозоне.Пробовал корректировать условия проверки,но всё же не могу понять что делаю не так.

IndexError: list index out of range

Возвращает список той же длины, что и list_l, где значение в индексе i равно True, если list_l[i] больше порогового значения, и False в противном случае

```
def elementwise_greater_than(list_l, thresh):
    new_list = []
    for i in range(len(list_l)):
        if list_l[i] >= thresh:
            i = True
            new_list[i] = i
        else:
            i = False
            new_list[i] = i
        continue
    return new_list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут проще вообще **списковое сокращение** использовать и сделать всё в одну строку, без излишеств:

```py
def elementwise_greater_than(list_l, thresh):
    return = [x > thresh for x in list_l]
```

А у вас в коде сразу несколько ошибок:

- использование переменной `i` одновременно и для индекса и для значения
- присваивание значения по индексу в **пустой список**
- знак сравнения выбран не верно, либо условие задачи сформулировано не чётко: "больше" - это `>`, а если вы пишете `>=`, то это "больше или равно" либо "не меньше".

Если вы хотите присваивать по индексу - нужно сначала сделать список нужного размера. Либо вместо присваивания использовать `.append`, как в другом ответе. Либо использовать списочное сокращение для создания списка, как в моём ответе.

Comment: Я понял, спасибо за рабочий вариант решения и,что даже более важно,указание на ошибки.Хорошего дня 

Answer (score 2):

Лучше делать через так:

```
def elementwise_greater_than(list_l, thresh):
    new_list = []
    for i in list_l:
        if i >= thresh:
            new_list.append(True)
        else:
            new_list.append(False)
        continue
    return new_list
```